# What is the German equivalent of foo, bar, baz?

Tags: translation

The English words *foo*, *bar* and *baz* are often used as placeholder nonsense names in programming. In French, "toto, titi, tata, tutu" are common.

Which words are used for this purpose in German code?

To clarify: Although company-local traditions are interesting, that's not what I'm asking about.

Comment: This reminds me of an April-Fools joke, where Microsoft introduces G# (German Sharp), a C# implementation with German keywords ;)

Comment: Better an April-Fools joke than the foolish German VBA they really created.

Comment: @bernd_k: Yes, and it's still in Excel. Did they do this for other languages as well? ;)

Comment: @oregonGhost Tja und dann gibt es noch viele deutsche Übersetzungen von guten Computerbüchern, wo die automatische Übersetzung große Teile der Programmbeispiele entstellt hat.

Comment: Mein Vorschlag für eine (mehr oder weniger) akkurate Übersetzung wäre *Zeug*, *Kneipe* und *Bartholomäus*. ;-)

Comment: @deceze: Das erinnert mich an eine Situation vor ein paar Monaten. Hatte mit einem Kollegen für einen Kunden eine Software mehr oder weniger fertig. Er hatte mir dann noch per IM eine Codezeile geschickt, die ungefähr aussah wie `... Get(b)`. Nun macht mein Instant-Messenger aus `(b)` natürlich ein Bierglas... Den Screenshot davon haben wir dem Kunden dann in der Mitteilung, dass alle Fehler behoben seien und offenbar auch der Code selbst dieser Meinung sei, mitgeschickt ;)

Comment: Random Wikipedia connection: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntaktische_Variable

Comment: @OregonGhost : they did it for french as well, alas.

Comment: @ogerard: With accents? :D

Comment: @OregonGhost : no, but worse: with different syntactic delimiters for parameters and cell addressing.

Comment: For me, `wrgl`, `xrgl`, `zrgl`, and the like are international enough to use them in any language. `:)`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Since programming is often deeply connected with the English language, I guess many if not most people use *foo*, *bar*, etc. too.

However there is of course *blub* and *blubber* or at my company *blurbs*, *blurbsi*, *blubberhupps* and the like are hot. It's sort of a local meme.

Comment: Yeah, *foo*/*bar* is fine. I often use *bla* and *blub* as well. Or even *blablabla* etc. :P

Comment: +1 for blubberhupps.

Comment: user of bla(bla) and blub(b) here, too!

Comment: +1 I also use foo and bar, and sometimes bla and blubb.

Comment: "many, if not most": nope. _foo_ and _bar_ are a red flag for me when reviewing and never get a pass. Because. :)

Answer (score 18):

You could go with *dings–bums*, *dingens–kirchens*, *bla–blubb–blafasel*. But if we are talking about programming context, then I wager the English placeholders *foo* and *bar* are the most popular by far.

Comment: +1 for *dingsbums*, great word :)

Comment: I use "bla" and "blubb", too. Additionally "laber", which can be extended to "laber-sülz", e.g. for testing Umlaut capabilities.

Answer (score 16):

*Bla* is sometimes used. And *Blub* if you need a second. But since the actual code language is typically English, not German, you can use the same as in English. In my company, however, you'll find a suspicious amount of `bunny` in code... Everybody likes bunnies.

I hate the use of foo, bar, baz, by the way. Better think of real examples. Now that I think about it, I rarely encountered German examples with foo, bar and baz. May be coincedence though.

Comment: Yes, when reading code (and trying to understand it), usage of `foo` doesn't really help.

Answer (score 5):

All German Programmers I know use foo / bar. So do I, most of the time, but my own private variation is:

Nase, Hase, Vase, Blase (etc.)

Comment: +1: You got me at *Hase*.

Comment: Das ist gut, werde ich in Zukunft auch verwenden. :-)

Answer (score 5):

A friend has told me that his professor extensively used “wilde” (= “wild”) and “wutz” (= diminutive of “boar”, “pig”) as metasyntactic variables. To this day, these are my favourites.

Comment: Wilde Wutz? Oo +1

Comment: +1, although *Wutz* is not a diminutive, but rather a word of its own right ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is not representative, but my first variable of choice is always "willi", followed by "otto" and then "franz"

Answer (score 1):

Ich nehm *eene, meene, miste*. Kommt glaub ich aus der [Augsburger Puppenkiste](http://www.augsburger-puppenkiste.de/). "Eene, meene, miste, es rappelt in der Kiste ...". Bedeutet, soweit ich weiß, in etwa das gleiche wie *foo bar baz*. :-)

Comment: Ne, das "eene meene miste" entstammt der "Rappelkiste", einer ZDF-Kleinkindersendung aus den 70er Jahren im Kielwasser der Sesamstraße, siehe http://www.fernsehserien.de/index.php?serie=555.

Answer (score 1):

*Muh*, *lala* and *bum*, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I once worked on a project where the temporary or test variables were always called [**Hugo**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugo). Don't know though if anyone else uses it.

Comment: I know *KarlHugo*, paired with *Klarabella*. Don't ask.

Comment: @OregonGhost: Mikki kommt mal her?

Comment: @ogerard: Maybe I misunderstand you, but shouldn't Klarabella be paired with Rudi Ross in that case, since it's Klarabella Kuh? ;)

Comment: Wahrscheinlich waren die Variablen alle für den Hugo. :-)